# Clean JSON from ServiceStack Service

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I am evaluating ServiceStack and I have followed some examples. However, the JSON that is returned looks like { key: arrayofobjects } instead of just { arrayofobjects }.

How can I return it so the JSON is cleaner and does not have the Response property as the key?

This is what is being returned:

```
{
    suburb: 
    {
      id: 1753,
      name: "Quorrobolong",
      postcode: "2325"
    }
}
```

This is what I am looking to have returned:

```
{
    id: 1753,
    name: "Quorrobolong",
    postcode: "2325"
}
```

The Service:

```
public class SuburbService : Service
{
    public ICacheClient CacheClient { get; set; }

    public object Get(Suburb request)
    {
       string cacheKey = UrnId.Create<Suburb>(request.Id);
       var resp = Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache<SuburbResponse>(CacheClient, cacheKey, () =>
       {
          return new SuburbResponse { Suburb = Db.LoadSingleById<Suburb>(request.Id) };
       });
       return resp;
    }
}
```

The Response:

```
public class SuburbResponse : IHasResponseStatus
{
  public Suburb Suburb { get; set; }
  public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The ORMLite POCO:

```
[Route("/suburbs", "PUT,POST,PATCH")]
[Route("/suburbs/{Id}")]
public partial class Suburb : IHasId<long> 
{

  [Alias("SuburbID")]
  [AutoIncrement]
  public long Id { get; set;}

  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set;}

  [Required]
  public string Postcode { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON ServiceStack is producing is clean; it's producing the response you have asked it for. But to get the flatter structure you desire you should make `SuburbResponse` inherit from `Suburb` instead of including it.

```cs
public class SuburbResponse : Suburb, IHasResponseStatus
{
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
```

In your return you can use ServiceStack's auto-mapper to map your `Suburb` to the response type, `SuburbResponse`.

**ServiceStack 3:**
You can [learn about v3 auto-mapper here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Auto-mapping).

```
using ServiceStack.Common;
...

return Db.LoadSingleById<Suburb>(request.Id).TranslateTo<SuburbResponse>();
```

**ServiceStack 4:**
You can [learn about v4 auto-mapper here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-mapping).

```
using ServiceStack;
...

return Db.LoadSingleById<Suburb>(request.Id).ConvertTo<SuburbResponse>();
```

Hope this helps. If you have any problems or further queries let me know in the comments.

Comment: Where is the TranslateTo<> extension?

Comment: You need to include `ServiceStack.Common`.

Comment: Yeah thought so from Googling, however I have ServiceStack.Common 4.0.3.0 referenced in project but I get error when adding using ServiceStack.Common ... any ideas?

Comment: I am just not getting .Common available in ServiceStack. If I inspect ServiceStack.Common reference in Object Explorer I can see DictionaryExtensions and 3 namespaces: ServiceStack, ServiceStack.Reflection and ServiceStack.Support. Reference added by NuGet.

Comment: What version of ServiceStack are you targeting v4 (latest, commercial) or v3 (open source)? What version is your `ServiceStack.dll` reporting?

Comment: v4. I just found a ConvertTo in ServiceStack.Text.

Comment: Also I didn't realise SS had moved to a commercial version. I will have to rollback to v3 for this current project.

Comment: Yeah it's a new thing. [See here](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki) for v3 instructions. `TranslateTo` is definitely in v3. v4 uses `ConvertTo`.